# Prove the following Injective and Surjective function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Prove that the following function is bijective (both injective and surjective):

$$f(x,y) = (x^2+y+x-2, x+3)$$

Usually I know how to do these, but the fact that the first x is squared, throws me off course. How can I tackle this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2$; then
\begin{cases}
x_1^2+y_1+x_1-2=x_2^2+y_2+x_2-2\\
x_1+3=x_2+3
\end{cases}
Can you deduce from this that $x_1=x_2$ *and* $y_1=y_2$? If so, you have proved that the function is injective.

Next, given $(a,b)$, can you find $(x,y)$ such that
\begin{cases}
x^2+y+x-2=a\\
x+3=b
\end{cases}
so as to prove that the function is surjective?

Comment: Though  I do understand the inyective part, I fail to do the same for the surjective. What should I look for with that set of equations??

Comment: @user143899 You have to solve it for $x$ and $y$. Since this is possible for any pair $(a,b)$ (just observe that $x=b-3$ and substitute in the first equation), the function is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y)=f(u,v)$ then $x+3=u+3$ so $x=u$. Now, $x^2+y+x-2=x^2+v+x-2$; hence, $y=v$. We have proved the injectivity.

For surjectivity, suppose that take any $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$. Suppose that $f(x,y)=(a,b)$. Then $x+3=b$ and $x=b-3$. Then, $(b-3)^2+y+b-3=a$ and $y=a-(b-3)^2-(b-3)=$$=a-(b-3)(b-2)$. Indeed, it can be easilty checked that $f(b-3,a-(b-3)(b-2))=(a,b)$, so $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inverse map is

$$f^{-1}(a,b) = (b-3, a-(b-1)(b-4))$$